# Web Scraping Event Handler Gets Stuck after pressing the "START" button - Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have written an Eventhandler (Asynchronous call) through which I download the source string (HTML) of any webpage, I enter the URL through a textbox and pass it to the method which calls the eventhandler, this works fine, except when:

I open the Application, do nothing and press the "START" button, open browser, copy any link to some page, press the "START" button again & run the application, and then when I paste that link into the text box and try scraping it, it gets stuck with my progress indicator in an infinite loop, I have tried refreshing page but it doesn't help, here's the code below:

```
 public void LoadSiteContent(string url)
 {
        //create a new WebClient object


        var indicator = new ProgressIndicator
        {
            IsVisible = true,
            IsIndeterminate = true,
            Text = "Downloading Source..."
        };

        try
        {
            SystemTray.SetProgressIndicator(this, indicator);

            WebClient client = new WebClient();

            client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(DownloadStringCallback2);

            client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex is TimeoutException || ex is WebException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("It seems there is no response from the remote server (are you connected to the internet?)");

            }
       }
 }

 private void DownloadStringCallback2(Object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
 {

            if (!e.Cancelled && e.Error == null)
            {
              //Do whatever with the downloaded string (e.Result)
            }
 }
 private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {


        string Entered_URL = "";

        Entered_URL = Enter_URL_Text.Text; //Stored from the textbox


        LoadSiteContent(Entered_URL);
 }
```

How do I get around this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code and it works just fine. I think it "appears" to be stuck in infinite loop because of the `ProgressIndicator`. You need to change it's `IsIndeterminate` and `Text` property in your `DownloadStringCallback2` method.

Try adding the following code to your `DownloadStringCallback2` method:

```
private void DownloadStringCallback2(Object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var indicator = SystemTray.GetProgressIndicator(this);
        indicator.IsIndeterminate = false;
        indicator.Text = "";

        if (!e.Cancelled && e.Error == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Page load complete.");

            //Do whatever with the downloaded string (e.Result)
        }
    }
```

and see if it works as expected.

Comment: Ok this did fix another problem with the progress indicator but my orignal problem is still there, its weird, after going through the steps I've posted in my main post, it just gets stuck inside the "LoadSiteContent" function it seems, and never gets to display the string downloaded, then there is a Hyperlink button I put on the same page which opens the browser, if I click that, open the browser and go back using the Back button on the phone and THEN try scraping (after all the steps), it works...

Comment: Hmm... maybe it's throwing an exception inside the try block which is getting caught silently by your catch block. Try removing the try catch blocks and run under debugger. Let me know if you get an exception.

Comment: Removed them and nope, no exceptions were being caught =/

Comment: What confuses me more is that once it shows no result, I invoke the browser with another button on that page and click "Back", then try scraping & it works....is this related to some session/stack being maintained at the back after I do the steps (after clicking the *Start* button and all?) but how can it be since I start the app from scratch after doing the steps in my first post...

Comment: I think if I could "Close" the application completely on clicking the START button, it would solve this problem.