# Close Application on START Button (Windows Phone 7)

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7

I want my application to be terminated after the "Start" button is clicked on windows phone, I do not know which event is fired by the Start button or how I can override it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Try this once -:**

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["isstartnav"] = true;
```

**Verify the above condition and call the below specified method:**

```
if (NavigationService.CanGoBack)
    {
        while (NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry() != null)
        {
            NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
        }
    }
```

This Method will remove the stack entries from the RAM and your app will be removed from the memory.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, under which event am I supposed to do perform this check? because I cannot see any "Start_Button_Clicked" event or something similar, or can it be checked anywhere in my code? Thanks!

Comment: PhoneApplicationService has the Global context.

You can check this anywhere.
once check it under simple if condition..

and plz rply your observation.

Comment: Ok that did not fix the problem it seems, I am trying to do this because of a problem I posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25246655/web-scraping-event-handler-gets-stuck-after-pressing-the-start-button-window

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, you can't. Only the user and the OS can close an app. Windows Phone 8 has an `Application.Terminate()` method, but with Windows Phone 7, you cannot do any such thing.

One hack is to throw some exception in your `Application.Deactivated` event. Doing so will result in an app crash and eventually close your app, but your app will fail certification at Windows Phone Store.

Comment: I see, where can I find this Application.Deactivated event? I've done this before and it did not fail the certification (because I did this behind a "close" button that I made myself). Thanks!

Comment: I see. The store requirement says "The app must handle exceptions raised by the any of the managed or native system API and not close unexpectedly." I guess doing it behind close button makes it expected.

Comment: Anyways, It is in `App.xaml.cs`. Look for `Application_Deactivated` event handler.